# Four blank line before the table

Tags: html

When I see it via browser I see four blank line before the table.  Where are they and how to remove them?

```
<body>
            <table>  
                <tr><td> Subject name:* </td><td>   <input type="text" name="subject_name"></td></tr>
                <br>   
                    <tr><td> Code of subject: </td><td> <input type="text" name="subject_code"></td></tr>
                    <br>
                        <tr><td> Description:*</td><td><input type="text" name="descriptions"></td></tr>
                        <br>
                            <tr><td> Teacher:*</td><td><input type="text" name="teacher"></td></tr>
                            <br>
                                <tr><td> Link:</td><td><input type="text" name="href"></td></tr>
                                <br>
                                    <tr><td> University:*</td><td><select id="continent" name="university" onchange="countryChange(this);">
                                                <option value="empty">Select a university</option>
                                                <option value="Chech technical university (CVUT)">Chech technical university (CVUT)</option>
                                                <option value="Charles university (UK)">Charles university (UK)</option>
                                                <option value="MIT">MIT</option>
                                                <option value="Harvard">Harvard</option>
                                            </select> </tr>

                                    </table>
                                    </body>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You place any tag outside of `<tr></tr>` tags, it will placed outside your table. Remove the `<br />` tags between `<tr>` tags and your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

Like t q and Shadow_boi mentioned, take out the `<br>` tags.  Also, your final `<td>` isn't closed.  Something like:

```
<body>
    <table>  
        <tr>
            <td> Subject name:* </td>
            <td>   <input type="text" name="subject_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Code of subject: </td>
            <td> <input type="text" name="subject_code"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Description:*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="descriptions"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Teacher:*</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="teacher"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Link:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="href"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> University:*</td>
            <td>
                <select id="continent" name="university" onchange="countryChange(this);">
                    <option value="empty">Select a university</option>
                    <option value="Chech technical university (CVUT)">Chech technical university (CVUT)</option>
                    <option value="Charles university (UK)">Charles university (UK)</option>
                    <option value="MIT">MIT</option>
                    <option value="Harvard">Harvard</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<br>` is used to break a line that is a sentence or a sequence of characters as they are aligned horizontally by default. `<br>` is used to print all the text or characters following it in a new line.In HTML `<table>` is a tag used to display a table with some contents. `<table>` should always be followed by `<tr>` which means you are adding a row into the table. `<tr>` can be read as starting of new `TABLE ROW`.Hence once you close this tag as  the following code would automatically considered to print from the next line as that row has ended already. `<td>` is used to give the description part,what should be shown on this new row that is inside a `<tr>` .Hence  is always placed inside a `<tr>` .You can consider this as a new column,so as many  as many columns in that row in that table.Here in this context you have closed `</tr>` telling the browser to display the other contents in a next line and again you have given a `<br>` . `<br>` is not allowed inside a table because of the above explanation hence as you are not using any divisions of forms in the code it is taking those `<br>` at the starting even before the table is displayed.Hence the four lines space before the table.Try removing the `<br>` and you will get the expected results.You can also refer t

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the < br > tags

or move the < br > tags inside < td > tags

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the breaks

```
            <table>  
            <tr><td> Subject name:* </td><td>   <input type="text" name="subject_name"></td></tr>

            <tr><td> Code of subject: </td><td> <input type="text" name="subject_code"></td></tr>

            <tr><td> Description:*</td><td><input type="text" name="descriptions"></td></tr>

            <tr><td> Teacher:*</td><td><input type="text" name="teacher"></td></tr>

            <tr><td> Link:</td><td><input type="text" name="href"></td></tr>

            <tr><td> University:*</td>
            <td><select id="continent" name="university" onchange="countryChange(this);">
                    <option value="empty">Select a university</option>
                    <option value="Chech technical university (CVUT)">Chech technical university (CVUT)</option>
                    <option value="Charles university (UK)">Charles university (UK)</option>
                    <option value="MIT">MIT</option>
                    <option value="Harvard">Harvard</option>
            </select> 
            </tr>

            </table>
```